# what is the url for viewing all comment from a facebook comment box pls?

Tags: facebook, url

If I put this url into the browser:

https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?api_key=MYAPID

It shows the comment box, but none of the comments are appearing. Can anyone tell what code code to add to that url or the correct url so I can view all the comments from a certain comment box app pls?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit all settings of that comment box here:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/?id=MYAPID

For a specific page you would use the following

https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?api_key=MYAPID&href=URLENCODEDHREF&view=recent_comments